# Cordova build failed on Android

Tags: android, cordova, android-5.0-lollipop

I was previously having Cordova which was building targeting Android-19, which worked perfectly fine.

Recently, I updated cordova and it has build target Android-22 now. But I am not able to build my cordova project.

I have already updated the Android SDK tools by using the SDK Manager.

What am I missing?

I am getting something like this:

[image]

Comment: what response if you type 'java'?

Answer (score 0):

Its little hard to tell from the screenshot. So i'll guess few steps

1. Update to Java 1.7
2. Finding what is causing this message to print "You may not have the required environment or OS...."

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the android platform again? From memory just run: 
Cordova platform add android